# Can I use pine and poplar together in trim?

Tags: wood, wood-selection, wood-movement, trim

Is it safe to use pine and poplar interior trim pieces together or will I have trouble later from things expanding/contracting differently in the future?  Specifically, I have pine door jambs and would add poplar doorstop trim.  Curious if poplar casing on pine door jambs would have issues too.  I'm guessing most people wouldn't hesitate to do this but I am extra cautious about having pieces warp later on.

Comment: Totally fine. (Assuming paint, rather than stain…)

Comment: *"or will I have trouble later from things expanding/contracting differently in the future? ...I am extra cautious about having pieces warp later on."* Warp is a completely different issue to the natural expansion/contraction cycle. Except in specific circumstanced that we don't need to concern ourselves with here, ALL wood expands and contracts in service. But very little of it warps. Do you need a primer on wood movement to help firm up on the relative rates of expansion/contraction along the different axes?

Comment: @Graphus Ok, "cautious about pieces warping" is too specific.  I'm cautious about not doing something stupid that will screw up my work later on.  What I was thinking is something like adjacent pieces moving out of unison and working fasteners loose or just cracking the paint.  Another primer on wood movement probably wouldn't kill me.  I think I've read them before but they just don't translate to subtle stuff like this for me.

Comment: Hi, can you provide images showing parts that concern you?

Comment: @Volfram I'll see if I can take one later but it's door stop molding, the ~1 inch wide strip on the face of a door jamb that keeps the door from swinging through.  That's the specific problem in front of me now but I do want to understand this in general, not just for this exact case.

Comment: I don't understand how you are worried about expanding/contracting 1" wide strip. If you calculate movement you will see how small it is, maybe 1/100"!!

Comment: @VolframK I am worried about expanding/contracting 1" wide strip because I don't know better and that is why I am asking questions.  But you are getting hung up on a specific example.  Now I'm putting up poplar 1x5s for door jambs and putting pine casing over it.  Is that also a baseless concern?  According to FreeMan's answer, probably yes.  I want to have a broad understanding.

Comment: No, not probably yes! Look at wood everywhere around you for examples. Does not matter what species, basic principles always the same.

Comment: @VolframK The "probably yes" was "yes, the concern is baseless."  Is that not what you're telling me?  You're getting on my case for not being confident in something that seems obvious to you.  What are these basic principles?  I don't know and I'm asking questions.  Wood everywhere around me is painted and a lot of the trim in my house is coming apart.  I don't have time to seek out finely crafted woodworking examples for study.

Comment: Basic principle is: wood changes width, not enough in thickness to worry until very thick (3-4" +) , and we never worry about length.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Every* piece of wood will expand and contract at somewhat different rates. Even two pieces of pine from the same tree will likely be different.

Old furniture (like a chest of drawers) used to be made of oak or maple or mahogany, while the backs were often made of pine because it was cheap and nobody would see it. If these pieces have lasted for centuries, there's no reason your jambs and trim made of poplar and pine will have any issues.

As noted in a comment, though, you'll want to paint this, not stain it. Poplar isn't a particularly pretty wood for staining, but it's *fantastic* for painting.

Comment: What makes it so fantastic for painting?

Comment: It's got a very tight grain that doesn't print through the paint. Makes it much easier to get a nice smooth finish with a minimum of prep time. Also, it's cheap. Maple also has a nice tight grain, but it's not so cheap... OTOH, poplar often has a greenish color to it that makes getting a nice looking stain job difficult because you end up with that green tinge coming through the stain.

Comment: @aquaticapetheory, FWIW the main reason I think you would want to paint a mixture of pine (softwood in general) and poplar is simply that paint is the great equaliser. If staining, unless you go out of your way in selecting the pieces *and* stain very dark you'll be able to spot the softwood boards a mile away! By comparison when you go into any interior space with painted trim it all comes together as a cohesive whole doesn't it? There's no telling what mixture of woods (and other materials, since MDF is now so commonly used in interiors) was used because it's all just one colour.

Comment: @FreeMan I've been sanding down the growth ring patterns on pine boards so I can definitely see that being the case and wish I'd used more poplar now.  I had read complaints on contractor forums claiming that poplar is worse for paint because it raises the grain more.

Comment: @Graphus I get that, i wasn't going to try to match two different wood species.  But it will be a bummer to paint everything because I have all this stain-grade pine trim that I think looks nice with no finish at all (except for the one lone douglas fir jamb I ripped from an old floor board because I ran out of straight pine 1x5s).

Comment: Forum denizens that complain about grain raising have forgotten the basics of painting. Prime, lightly sand between coats, apply at least 2 finish coats. (Not rocket surgery!)

Comment: Well, @aquaticapetheory, you are, of course, always welcome to stain your poplar and have the mismatched grain show through, just like it will with the Doug Fir. It's your house and you're the one who has to live with it. I was attempting to offer up some of the conventional wisdom. I've not tried staining poplar myself, but I can see where it wouldn't match the look of pine at all. It might just be time to bite the bullet and buy some pine stock that you can mill down, or live with what you've got. Only you can make that call.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate, well put. I would have imagined that any pro would accept grain raising as just par for the course, and, one could argue that a true pro might pre-raise the grain in as many cases as possible. Assuming waterbased paint naturally, with oil-based primer and/or paint it's basically a non-issue.

Comment: @FreeMan, despite its reputation to the contrary it's possible to get good stain results with poplar (although it won't look like softwood naturally). Any evident green or blue streaking is always a potential worry, but where the green tinge is slight and the desired final colour is dark enough it's not a huge PITA.. Especially now with the wide acceptance of "gel stain" which can solve a lot of stain issues (like blotching in cherry as well as all the softwoods)..... as long as you're OK with how it obscures grain, which of course is no issue with poplar.

Comment: @FreeMan I'm not disagreeing with your conventional wisdom.  It was already decided that the trim will be painted.  This is why I am using poplar pieces.  But it will be a pity to cover up all that nice pine.

Comment: @aquaticapetheory Go ahead and stain it. If you don't like it, paint it. Highly recommend doing it in this order. The other way is much harder.